# derived class member function failed in c++

Tags: c++

To make long story short:

```
class A {
        public:
              A();
              ~A();
              void SetID(char* ID);
              char* GetID();
        protected:
              char ID[10];
};

class B: public A {
        public:
              B();
              ~B();
        protected:
              ...
        private:
              ...
};
```

Then in main:

```
 ...
 B *temp = new B;
 temp->SetID("0x12345678");
 ...
```

Then the compiler said "Expected constructor,destructor or type conversion before -> token" where "temp->SetID("0x12345678")" lies

Anyone gimme some hints??

Whole Program as Loki suggested:

```
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace std;

  class A {
      public:
         A();
         ~A();
         void SetID(char* id);
         char* GetID();
       protected:
            char ID[10];
   };

   void A::SetID(char* id){
         strcpy(ID,id);          
    }
    char* A::GetID(){
         return ID;
    }
    class B: public A {
             public:
                 B();
                ~B();
             protected:
                int num;
     };


    int main(){
    B *temp = new B;
    B->SetID("0x12345678");
    cout<<B->GetID()<<endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Try `new B()`. You also misspelled `protected` in `B`.

Comment: @chris: As `B` has user declared default constructor `new B` and `new B()` do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Did you try: void SetID(**const** char* ID)?

Comment: @CharlesBailey, ah. I thought you had to specify when using `new`. My bad then.

Comment: Please post a complete compilable example that exhibits the error which you are getting.

Comment: My bad everyone.@CharlesBailey

Comment: This might give you some hints. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new>

Regards

Comment: Make it short but make the code valid. We want to cut and paste the code and see what the compiler says. If you leave shitty code that has other errors in it then it is hard to find the problem you want solved. `...` does not a program make.

Comment: @LokiAstari money suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `B`, which is a type, where you probably meant to use `temp` which is the name of the variable.

Instead of:

```
int main(){
B *temp = new B;
B->SetID("0x12345678");
cout<<B->GetID()<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

You probably meant:

```
int main(){
B *temp = new B;
temp->SetID("0x12345678");
cout<<temp->GetID()<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

which is more like the "excerpt" that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess.

You have closed `main` by an unpaired curly brace before you got to this code that you believe is in `main`.  So it is outside of any function, and that is no place for expressions other than initializers.